# Hot Reload | Live Reload for big Spring Boot Project

Tags: java, spring-boot, deployment, devops, continuous-deployment

I am building a POC for the Hot Reload for a big Spring Boot Project which is linked to git, many developers involved in the development and have multiple environments SIT, UAT and Prod

As a simple implementation for it, to add the dependencies and do some configuration on the IDE and run the application from the IDE itself.

Let us say that we are having some servers and external web servers that we need to host the .war file into it, Git, many developers working on it, how can we have this project configured as Hot Reload thing.